# Did Old English have a middle voice or mediopassive voice?

Tags: grammar, old-english, middle-voice

I've read that Icelandic and Old Norse have a middle voice, so I wanted to know if either or both of these distinct grammatical features existed in Old English.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)#Middle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediopassive_voice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from what Mitchell & Robinson say in *A Guide to Old English*, no.

Verb forms in OE only have one voice - the active voice. 
The one exception is the word *hātte* (is called, was called).

If someone wanted to indicate the passive voice in OE, using any other verb besides *hātte*, they'd either

- use *man* (one, one person, someone, anyone) alongside the verb in the active voice, or
- they'd use 'to be' or 'to become' alongside a past participle.

I suppose that just because Mitchell & Robinson don't mention a 'middle voice' doesn't mean that OE writers never indicated things which would take a middle voice in a language that has a form for it. Perhaps someone else can comment more knowledgeably on that.

Comment: Isn't "hātte" just an intransitive verb? The fact that it's translated into modern English as a passive ("is called") isn't sufficient to say that it's passive in Old English.

Comment: sumelic, that may be true. I'm not an expert, but I happened to have a copy of *A Guide to OE* on my desk when I saw this question, so my answer is a summary of what I found there. Mitchell and Robinson do call *hātte* a "true passive".  They say: "One true passive form survives from an earlier stage of the language, viz. *hātte*..." (Mitchell & Robinson, §89).

Comment: Oh, I see! I hadn't realized that

Comment: Great source. Indeed, there is no morphological passive. Passive voice is almost all periphrastic or contextual in OE. In Hogg and Alcorn, *An Introduction to Old English* (2012), they say the same thing (esp. p. 83-4). "Despite the above [that passive voice was formed from periphrasis or from using *man*], there did exist in Old English one morphological passive, namely ha ̄tte , hatton , passive forms of ha ̄tan ‘call’. ... It is probably foolish to attach too much importance to this morphological passive. It looks rather like an idiomatic relic."